# Python OpenCV - ConvexHull error "Points is not a numpy array, neither a scalar"?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, opencv

I'm trying to run some Convex Hull image processing. Basically what I want to do is to close off an open contour.

I found [this answer over at the opencv forum](http://answers.opencv.org/question/74777/how-to-use-approxpolydp-to-close-contours/?answer=74878#post-id-74878) and it's exactly what I wanted to do. I started converting the code from C++ to Python some time ago. I succeeded with converting the code of the question, but the code for the answer is giving me a tougher time than expected.

This is what I have so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def contoursConvexHull(contours):
    print("contours length = ", len(contours))
    print("contours length of first item = ", len(contours[1]))
    pts = []
    for i in range(0, len(contours)):
        for j in range(0, len(contours[i])):
            pts.append(contours[i][j])

    result = cv2.convexHull(pts)
    return result

# Get our image in color mode (1)
src = cv2.imread("source.png", 1);

# Convert the color from BGR to Gray
srcGray = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Use Gaussian Blur 
srcBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(srcGray, (3, 3), 0)

# ret is the returned value, otsu is an image
ret, otsu = cv2.threshold(srcBlur, 0, 255,
                          cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Use canny
srcCanny = cv2.Canny(srcBlur, ret, ret*2, 3)

# im is the output image
# contours is the contour list
# I forgot what heirarchy was
im, contours, heirarchy = cv2.findContours(srcCanny,
                                           cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                           cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

cv2.drawContours(src, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

ConvexHullPoints = contoursConvexHull(contours)
cv2.polylines(src, [ConvexHullPoints], True, (0, 255, 255), 2)


cv2.imshow("Test", src)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And when I'm trying to run it, it's giving me

```
    result = cv2.convexHull(pts)
TypeError: points is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

And I'm guessing that I'm feeding the `convexHull` an input and it wants something else.

I'm pretty decent at C++ but I'm a total beginner at Python. I think I may be doing something wrong with I'm appending the contour elements to the `pts` list?

And honestly, I'm not all too sure why we need to append the points back to a new array, there doesn't seem to be any value manipulation or rearrangement that's going on.

Here's the C++ code for reference:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

vector<Point> contoursConvexHull( vector<vector<Point> > contours )
{
    vector<Point> result;
    vector<Point> pts;
    for ( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
        for ( size_t j = 0; j< contours[i].size(); j++)
            pts.push_back(contours[i][j]);
    convexHull( pts, result );
    return result;
}

int main( int, char** argv )
{
    Mat src, srcGray,srcBlur,srcCanny;

    src = imread( argv[1], 1 );
    cvtColor(src, srcGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    blur(srcGray, srcBlur, Size(3, 3));

    Canny(srcBlur, srcCanny, 0, 100, 3, true);

    vector<vector<Point> > contours;

    findContours( srcCanny, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(srcCanny.size(), CV_8UC3);

    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar( 255,255,255);
        drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2 );
    }

    vector<Point> ConvexHullPoints =  contoursConvexHull(contours);

    polylines( drawing, ConvexHullPoints, true, Scalar(0,0,255), 2 );
    imshow("Contours", drawing);

    polylines( src, ConvexHullPoints, true, Scalar(0,0,255), 2 );
    imshow("contoursConvexHull", src);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error say that `pts` is not an numpy array; its a python `list`.

To convert `pts` to an array, import numpy and do the simple conversion:

```
import numpy as np

# code ....

pts = np.array(pts)
result = cv2.convexHull(pts)
```

Comment: This works so far as to make the code run. However, I'm still not getting the results I expected.

Comment: thats trickier, but hopefully I answered your original question. You can update your question to reflect the new problem. In fact, consider asking a new question.

Comment: I got it, I just had to enclose the `ConvexHullPoints` with square brackets and the code is working as intended.